# Get Center point from source of a layer in OL OSM

Tags: angular, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am using Open layer OSM map with Angular to browse countries then states and then cities accordingly. I am able to level up as per selction and adding new layer for each. I am not removing but Just hidding previous layer suppose if someone selected New york from United states then all countries layer will be made hidden and upper layer with NewYark Cities will be visible. Now I need to give user ability to drill back to Upper level. Like double clicking on New York will display back all counties. so to do it when I hide current Layer and show previous layer it shows correctly but I am unable to retrieve its center point. can any one help in it ?

```
this.map.on('singleclick', (event) => {
    // do foreach for each layer  this.MapLevel is each layer number in map
    this['vectorLayer' + this.MapLevel].getFeatures(event.pixel).then((features) => {
        if (!features.length) {
          selection = {};
          return;
        }
        const feature = features[0];
        if (!feature) {
          return;
        }
        source: new VectorSource({source: new VectorSource({
          url: this.MapSourceURl, // local json file path to retrive Data
          map: this.map,
          format: new GeoJSON(),
          wrapX: false,
          useSpatialIndex: false,
          overlaps: false 
         })}); // layer parameters not pasting here as it has long
        this.map.addLayer(this['vectorLayer' + this.MapLevel]);
        this['vectorLayer'+ this.MapLevel].setVisible(true);
        this['vectorLayer' + (this.MapLevel - 1)].setVisible(false);
      });
      });


// On double click I am trying to show previous layer to downgrade Level in map

this.map.on('dblclick', (event) => {



this['vectorLayer' + (this.MapLevel-1)].getSource().forEachFeature(function (feature){
         var Coords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
 }); // i want to get outer boundary co-ordinated rather than per feature co-ordinates

     this['vectorLayer' + (this.MapLevel - 1)].setVisible(true);
     this['vectorLayer' + (this.MapLevel - 1)].setOpacity(1);
     this['vectorLayer'+ this.MapLevel].setVisible(false);
    });

But I am not getting correct zoom level of previous layer this so this code is failing.
```